# Process.Start(FilePath) with commas

Tags: c#, windows

When searching a directory for files of a specific name driven by the `_fileToSearch` parameter, I then create a custom list of `DrawingFound` and store the files path in a string called `FileDirectory`.

I then require on a button click `OpenDrawing()` for the file stored within `FileDirectory` to open to the user. This works in most cases, however, if the path has a `,` for example then the explorer defaults to opening the users documents directory. How can I handle commas within a file path to achieve the desired outcome?

```
public partial class DrawingFound
{
    public string DrawingName;
    public string FileType;
    public string FileDirectory;
    public string Revision;

    public void OpenDrawing()
    {
        Process.Start("Explorer.exe", FileDirectory);
    }
}

public void GetDrawings()
{
    string _searchFolder = @"C:\Users\ThisUser\Documents";
    string _fileToSearch = "Example of file, where a comma is used.txt";

    ObservableCollection<DrawingFound> _drawings = new();
    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new(_searchFolder);
    FileInfo[] files = dirInfo.GetFiles($"*{_fileToSearch}*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    foreach (FileInfo file in files)
    {
        if (!_drawings.Any(item => $"{item.DrawingName}{item.FileType}" == file.Name))
        {
            _drawings.Add(new DrawingFound
            {
                DrawingName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name),
                FileType = file.Extension,
                FileDirectory = file.FullName,
                Revision = "- Ignore -"
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That should be a `@` rather than a `$`.

Comment: Also it doesn't hurt to put any paths you pass to explorer inside embedded quotes

Comment: the problem is not with comma but rather with the space.

the system treats the characters before the space as "file path" and the rest as "parameters"

wrap the entire path in "embedded quotes"

Comment: I just tested using "First-Second.txt", "First,Second.txt" and "First Second.txt" and they all opened in Notepad, exactly as expected. Something else is going on in your app.

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: `Process.Start(@"C:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop\Test, comma.txt")` opens Notepad with that file, as expected (.NET Framework 4.8). Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @jmcilhinney thank you for pointing these guidelines out to me. I do apologise for this and have rewrote my question to better suit.

Comment: @Shadyjunior: Thank you. I must point out, though, that your example is not minimal yet: For example, I'm pretty sure that the problem still occurs if you remove the `Revision` from your `DrawingFound` type. To get good answers here on StackOverflow, you need to reduce it **as much as possible**.

Comment: @Shadyjunior: And your example is not complete either: There is no `void Main()`, and `OpenDrawing` is never called. I strongly suggest that you re-read the guidelines. The exact meanings of **minimal** and **complete** are important. It's probably easiest to start from a new Console project.

Comment: @Heinzi understood! I shall update accordingly, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

depending on your OS, you may need to use "escaping"

For example, to store a string `one "two" three` in a literal delimited with quotation marks, you need to escape the quotation marks. Depending on the language and environment, the "escape character" can be e.g. a `\`

in this example:

```
foo = "one \"two\" three"
```

I hope this helps; otherwise, please be more specific about your language, OS, e.t.c.

Comment: I don't think that's relevant. You have to escape a double-quote in a `string` literal because they denote the start and end of the literal. Commas are a different matter.

Comment: The reason why this is relevant, is because (apparently) `Process.Start(FilePath);` uses space as the "command delimiter" and whatever is after space, is a parameter of that command

Hence, one either needs to escape the spaces, 

or somehow inform the enclosing function that the entire string is a path rather than a path and parameters

Comment: Nope. That would be true if you called `Shell` but `Process.Start` uses separate parameters for the file to be executed and the commandline arguments.

Comment: @jmcilhinney OK, I give up, no more ideas here.

Comment: I have added additional information to show the actual use case for this issue. My apologies for not being clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone for your assistance with this matter. I managed to fix the issue and the operation now works as expected. @George Rey following your example I added the escape characters to achieve this:

```
Process.Start("explorer.exe", $"\"{FileDirectory}\"");
```

Answer (score -1):

After you did your edits, the problem is more clear:

I guess that your OS is windows.

The problem is not with the comma but rather with the space.

The system treats the characters before the space as "file path" and the rest as "parameters." This is for historical reasons.

wrap the entire path in "embedded quotes" so that it is clear to the OS that the entire string is a path. This should prevent it from trying to elide the command parameters out of that string

Comment: This is not true. If you called `Shell` it would matter but `Process.Start` has separate `fileName` and `arguments` parameters.